# bruteforce-code is not running

Tags: c, brute-force

I tried to code a litle bruteforce programm. But i cant compile it. Its a really easy programmcode i think and thats the reason why its bug me so hard that it didnt compile. I searched for solutions but couldnt strike a bonanza...

```
`1 #include <stdio.h>
 2 #include <string.h>
 3 char pass;
 4 strcpy(pass,"m");
 5 int pass_test(int argc, char *argv[]){
 6         char s_pass[2];
 7         argv[0] = s_pass;
 8         if (s_pass == pass){
 9                 printf("=================\n==Access gained==\n=================");
10 }               
11         else{
12                 printf("sth. went wrong");
13 }               
14 }
15 int main(){
16         char solved_pass[2];
17         char *OP_ABC;
18         int i, p, z;
19         strcpy(OP_ABC, "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz");
20         if ((strlen(pass)) == 1){
21                 for(i=0;i < strlen(OP_ABC);i++){
22                         pass_test(OP_ABC[i]);
23 }                       
24 }
25         if (strlen(pass) == 2){
26                 for(p=0;p < strlen(OP_ABC);p++){
27                         for(z=0;z < strlen(OP_ABC);z++){
28                                 OP_ABC[p] = solved_pass[0];
29                                 OP_ABC[z] = solved_pass[1];
30                                 pass_test(solved_pass);
31 }                               
32 }               
33 }
34 }`
```

this is what the compiler says

`bruteforce.c:4:13: error: expected ‘)’ before string constant
    bruteforce.c: In function ‘pass_test’:
    bruteforce.c:8:13: warning: comparison between pointer and integer [enabled by default]
    bruteforce.c: In function ‘main’:
    bruteforce.c:20:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    In file included from bruteforce.c:2:0:
    /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
    bruteforce.c:22:4: error: too few arguments to function ‘pass_test’
    bruteforce.c:5:5: note: declared here
    bruteforce.c:25:2: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘strlen’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
    In file included from bruteforce.c:2:0:
    /usr/include/string.h:399:15: note: expected ‘const char *’ but argument is of type ‘char’
    bruteforce.c:30:5: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘pass_test’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
    bruteforce.c:5:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
    bruteforce.c:30:5: error: too few arguments to function ‘pass_test’
    bruteforce.c:5:5: note: declared here`

Could somebody help me please ?

Comment: When posting code, please refrain from adding line-numbers. Instead mark out (with a comment for example) the lines that cause the problems you're having.

Comment: You are calling a function(`strcpy`) in file scope and that too, copying a string into a `char`. You have to pass two arguments to `pass_test` and you pass just one. You also copy a string into an uninitialized `char` pointer(`OP_PASS`)

Comment: @CoolGuy why does the function 'pass_test' requires 2 arguments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One* problem is that you can't have statements or free expression in the global scope.

Another problem is that the `strcpy` function expects a *string* (i.e. a `char*`) as the destination, not a single `char`.

You can solve both these problems by doing definition and initialization in one line:

```
char pass = 'm';
```